# CGI::Ajax can not control returned table css style?

Tags: ajax, perl, jquery-ui, cgi, tablesorter

I have question regarding using CGI::Ajax.

my CGI::Ajax registered function will return a table, and I want to control the table's style by using jquery plugin tablesorter

the result table is returned, but I just can not control the style of it, i.e, I can not sort the table with using the plugin tablesorter in calling function

major part of code is as below, these are just part of the code, if there are some punctuation problems, please ignore it

as you can see, the main program, "show_html", can sort the table, "metatable"; however, the return table, "resulttable" can not be sorted even if I put id='resulttable' there.

Could someone help me with this issue?

Thank you

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $pjx = CGI::Ajax->new('js_fun'=>\&perl_fun);

sub per_fun{
...
print $cgi->start_table({id=>'resulttable'}),
...
}



sub show_html{ //partial code
print $html_fh $cgi->start_html(
  -title=>'Selected GEO MetaData',

  -style=> {-src=>[ "jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css",
            "jq_tablesorter/themes/green/style.css",
        "jq_ui_redmond/css/selectable.css",
          ]
    },    
  -script=>[
            { -type => "text/javascript",
              -src => "$tempdir/jq/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
            },
            { -type => 'text/javascript',
              -src => "$tempdir/jq/jq_tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"
            },
    { -type => 'text/javascript',
              -src => "$tempdir/jq/jq_ui_redmond/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"
            },
           q<
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#metatable").tablesorter();
            $("#resulttable").tablesorter();
     )}

      ....


 $("#done").click(function(){
            $("#metatable").slideUp();
            js_fun(['val1'],['result1']); //ajax
            return false;
            })


.....

print $cgi->div({id=>'result1'});

.....
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what runs where.

Comment: I know what I run, but I don't know why the returned table cannot be controlled by tablesorter.

Comment: Well, if you insist, OK then. In any case, post a short, but complete script that actually compiles and runs and exhibits the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

The binding of the result table to the sort method has to be redone after the AJAX request returns successfully, something like this:

```
$.post("ajax/jsfun", "['val1']", function(data) {
    $('#resulttable').html(data);
    $("#resulttable").tablesorter();
    });
```